# URL PHP - no difference between letters

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

I've got a problem with my website, basically I am trying to move my website from one server to another with the database. The problem is in URL address, because I've got few thousands records in my database which include link to the images, most images links looks like this :

```
example.com/G/a/S/zx/A/img.jpg
```

and

```
example.com/g/A/s/zx/B/img.jpg
```

and the problem is that `/G/a/S/zx/` and `/g/A/s/zx/` its the same location but with capital letters.

How I can tell my server to check links with out letters validation ?? 
I want to make a rule that will tell the server that there is no difference between `/G/a/S/zx/` and `/g/A/s/zx/`

Comment: you need to fix it in DB or the server. or move to a windows based hosting (not recommended as you may get into more trouble later)

Comment: but it works on my old server, you can get the image from /G/a/S/zx/ and /g/A/s/zx/

Comment: not sure if this is what you want, but have a look at apache mod_spelling http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_speling.html

Comment: your old server OS may be windows, where there is no difference between upper and lower case.

Comment: @MarkS I won't recommend another mod as it may not be available on the next server. and who knows the OP has enough rights to add another module to the server.

Answer (score 0):

2 solutions that are way simpler than the direction you are thinking at:

1. Update the database records to have the proper paths
2. Update the directory names to have the same uppercase/lowercase names as your original server.

I presume you don't have the rights to change the case of the directories, so you'll just have to update in the database. Should not take long.

```
update table
set url = replace(url, 'old/path', 'NEW/PATH')
```

Answer (score 0):

Unix servers are case sensitive so that is why you get this kind of behavior.
Just rename-transform all your files' names to lowercase and do the same for the file links in your database so you will have consistency.